# I love "how" or "that"(?) you take care of the dog

Tags: grammar

> 1. I love **how** you take care of the dog.
> 2. I love **that** you take care of the dog.

Which is correct?

If they're both correct, do they mean the same thing? What's the difference between *how* and *that* in sentences like these?

Comment: Either is correct, depending upon what you want to say.  You may have better luck in English Language Learners  Stack Exchange. http://ell.stackexchange.com

Comment: Which meaning are you looking for?  "I love _the process_ how you take care of the dog." or "I love _the fact_ that you take care of the dog."

Comment: Only Americans would say "I love that you take care of your dog". To British (and Australian/ NewZealanders) it sounds ghastly. But if you want to sound truly American, go for it.

Comment: @IanS, can I ask which part of that sounds ghastly to non-American English-speakers? The "that," or something else? I'm truly curious.

Comment: @vanderpn, indeed it is 'that' ... I'm struggling to express why though - some constructions are ok, e.g.
-  I understand that you are back;
-  I heard that they are back.
But not e.g.
* I love that you are back;
* I hate that they are back.
You would need to substitute 'how' instead of 'that' for these last two examples to be correct in Commonwealth English (I hope I'm not overgeneralizing on the geographic range - I'm not sure about Canada).

Comment: @IanS: (1) Are Americans the only English speakers besides British (and Australian/New Zealanders)? (2) How does *I love **the fact** that you take care of the dog* sound to you? That's what is meant by the "American" shortened form *I love that you take care of the dog*.

Comment: @IanS: I'm American, and I would compare "I love that you take care of your dog" to "would you please hand me that piano?" — both perfectly natural and grammatically correct ways of expressing a thought that you would probably never have. By contrast, "I love [or appreciate] that *you* take care of *my* dog (when I'm out of town)" seems exceedingly natural. How does that sound to you? ... ... (Attribution: "Please hand me that piano." by George Carlin)

Comment: @Drew, yes, in British/Commonwealth English you could say 'I love the fact that you take care of your dog'. On your other point, of course you are right, there are plenty of other countries with English as the official language, in Africa for instance. Perhaps I should have said the 'industrialised Commonwealth countries'.

Comment: @Scott, your first example, "I love that you take care of my dog" still doesn't sound natural to me. As to "I appreciate that you take care of my dog," it would sound alright only as the first part of a conjunctive sentence, e.g. "... but I still don't want to marry you". Otherwise, as a standalone statement, we'd say "I appreciate you taking care of my dog.". It's a pity I can't summon up a good linguistic explanation for all of this. However, Tracy Chapman singing "The love that you had in your heart is gone" is fine, but I think that's because in her case 'love' is used as a noun.

Comment: @IanS Not to grill you :) but is it particular to the verbs *love* and *hate* then? Do any of these other verbs strike you as ungrammatical there: *imagine, presume, suppose, think, insist, conclude, see, hear* ?

Comment: Honestly, I think putting questions like this on hold seems pointlessly punitive. Can we not do this? It's clear to *me* what this person is asking (or, failing that, what they appear to need help with). Blocking further answers just prevents people from helping other people.

Comment: @JasonOrendorff: If it's clear to you what the OP is asking, maybe you should [edit] the question so it will be clear to the rest of us. I voted to close as unclear because, as the very first comment points out, they are both correct, but they mean different things. It's similar to asking, of "I like what I get" and "I get what I like", which one is correct. The question isn't answerable without a specification of what meaning is intended. (Attribution: "Then you should say what you mean." the March Hare went on. — from *Alice's Adventures in Wonderland* by Lewis Carroll.)

Comment: @JasonOrendorff, its intriguing. For Brit/Aus/NZ, the verbs that can't be used in the construction "I [verb] that you went" include love, hate, like, get, take. All these transitives need 'it' as an object after the verb. The others in your list don't need 'it'. It's not just fronted pronouns either: "I love that the train toots" sounds bad too. The same problem occurs if the conjunction 'when' is substituted for 'that' ("I hate when you bite"). 'How' (conj) seems to be a slightly different case. See too Dot Wordsworth's article in The Spectator online 01/08/2015 "Why I hate ‘I love that…’"

Comment: @Scott: Edited - take a look... My assumption is that the OP erroneously believed that only one of the two sentences was acceptable English. It seems kinder to read it that way that than to suppose that the OP has asked us a question that hinges on the actual situation with the OP's friend and the friend's dog, but failed to share those details with us. (Admittedly, we do get some truly unreasonable questions sometimes!)

Answer (score 2):

Both sentences mean what they say.

*I love how you take care of the dog*: This means that you appreciate that I pet the dog, play with the dog, feed the dog, give the dog treats, take the dog for walks, clean up after the dog, groom the dog, take the dog to the vet, etc.

*I love that you take care of the dog*: This means that you appreciate the simple fact that I take care of the dog in some way, and that that's what matters to you, not necessarily exactly how I take care of the dog. You might appreciate that I take care of the dog for any number of reasons. For example, it makes you think I'm a *dog person*, which in your mind is a good thing for me to be; after all, if I'm a *dog person*, I must be a decent human being in general, right? Or, maybe you appreciate that I take care of the dog because it's a lot of work, and you don't have the time for it.

Based on @IanS's comment, I agree that *I love that you take care of the dog* could be interpreted to mean *I love how you take care of the dog* if you think of the latter in the following sense: *How I love it that you take care of the dog.* I also agree that one could replace *I love that you take care of the dog* with *I love the fact that you take care of the dog*.

Comment: I'm still not buying it. I'm aware that the second example is of a construction U.S. English, and that it is valid there. I also understand the semantic distinction you are attempting. But for British-Australian-New Zealand speakers, the second example would need to be either "I love the way that ..." or "I love the fact that ...", or even "I love how you take care of the dog" (i.e., identical to the first example), for which - depending on context - it can have either the connotation of "I admire your compassion for dogs" or "I admire your dog grooming skills.".

Comment: @IanS I'm just trying to respond to the OP's question. :-) I take your points though. There's more than one way to read the first sentence; I gave the literal interpretation. The second sentence could perhaps benefit from the insertion of "the fact that".